# ruby on rails: Spork and Guard: no reaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I followed the rails tutorial to install Spork and Guard:
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2#sec:first_tests
Guard and Spork work when started separately, but when using it together, it hangs with the last output line "Spork is ready and listening on 8989!" without executing any tests.
I even used the argument :wait => 60 as described on https://github.com/guard/guard-spork

Any idea?

And by the way, if I should post the Gemfile or the Guardfile, is there any way to paste it without manually indenting each line by 4 spaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the " blockquote or {} codeblock buttons to automatically highlight or indent.

Setting up my tests gave me some trouble too as I followed along with the same tutorial. I got lucky by looking for other tutorials (some are listed below) and playing around with different gems and gem versions. Some things I learned the hard way in playing around with gem versions:

1) Calling "guard" from your project directory and calling "bundle exec guard" may or may not execute the same version of the guard gem, if you have more than one version installed. I recommend reading about bundler if you suspect gem versions might be giving you trouble. I know they gave me trouble.

2) The definitive version of the gem you are using for your project is listed in Gemfile.lock, but you're not supposed to modify that file. Modify the Gemfile with specific gem versions to get the right version installed.

[Type One Error](http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/tutorial-rails-with-rspec-spork-and-guard-from-scratch),
[The Carbon Emitter](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2010/12/10/speedy-test-iterations-for-rails-3-with-spork-and-guard/)

Comment: Thanks, I created a new rails application with exactly the same gems and steps described in the tutorial, and the Guard/Spork still hangs at the end.Anyway, I give it up now

Answer (score -1):

I hope you realize that when you first start guard and spork together it isn't supposed to execute any tests? It waits until you change a file, and then runs the tests for that file that changed. Or if you want it to run all specs, just hit your  key.